# backbone model for composite view without any data on its own

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller

I have a composite view as follows.

```
-------------------------------------
        fixed nav bar
-------------------------------------
            |
fixed       |
topics list | detail pane
            |
-------------------------------------
```

When you click on a topic, I am replacing the detail pane.
Navbar, Topics list and Detail all have models, but the top level app view doesn't.

In this case:

1. Should I declare a model for app view as well?
2. If so, should that model call fetch for individual models?
3. I read that the router should call model.fetch(). However, for a composite view the router needs to know about all the models. Should the router really care?

Also, what is the backbone equivalent of a controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a top-level app view at all? If it never changes and doesn't have a model, you don't need Backbone to manage it. You could create the elements for your other views in your HTML, and let your router update the detail pane to suit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need an app level model.
2. No. You need not. You can have individual topics call their own view / model inside the function in the router. See the psuedo code below.
3. You can call based on the topic inside the topic click event.

For eg,

Topic A : 
   Topic B :

```
Router.extend{

routes:
{
  Topic A : callA();
  Topic B : callB();
},

callA(){

 //call the view for A which can load the model (recommended)
 // or call the model directly here and bind it to the parent view itself. 
},


    callB(){

 //call the view for A which can load the model (recommended)
 // or call the model directly here and bind it to the parent view itself. 
  }
 };
```

Hope this helps.

Also for the last question, backbone uses 
Router as (MVC)controller/presenter
View.js and html will be like view 
Model will be the model.

This link may help too.

http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc